# Store json bases data for limited time

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, redis, sql-server-2014

I used MSSQl to store some JSON formated data in varchar datatype, but i wanna to remove rows that passed 3day after creation date.
Now i used some job to do this, but we have to removed millions number of row each day, i think to store this data in redis and set expire date for it, but have not experience with redis in large number of keys on it ( 1.5 millions key per day). redis can reliable in this case? is it good approach? can you suggest any better approach ?

Comment: Consider using MS Sql partitions https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191174(v=sql.105).aspx .

Comment: I think redis is a good option, the only need you should consider is memory. Find [here](http://redis.io/topics/faq) Redis FAQ.